# Pass instance variable to controller test in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm adding to test to an existing project. I have a user class that is assigned a unique url on create ad then is redirected to a path that contains that url.

I'm following the rspec book and wrote this test

```
it 'redirects to users#show' do
  post :create, user: attributes_for(:guest)
  expect(response).to redirect_to guest_path(:guest)
end
```

I get this back when I run the test.

```
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/guest/guest> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/guest/h7gutr1CMYxa5VNgWH5l1A>
```

The redirect the controller is sending back is correct but I am obviously writing the test incorrectly. How can I alter the expectation to pass the test?

Edit: Got a little closer, but still not there. Using

```
expect(response).to redirect_to guest_path(assigns(:user))
```

gives:

```
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/guest/1> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/guest/zaOVsiPBwQ4yNnC0mJNoNA>
```

using:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to guest_path(assigns(:user))
```

gives:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `url' for :user:Symbol
```

Solution:

I couldn't figure out how to call methods on the instance variable. It's done like this:

```
it 'redirects to users#show' do
  post :create, user: attributes_for(:guest)
  expect(response).to redirect_to guest_path(assigns(:user).url)
end
```

Comment: Did you use `assigns(:guest)` rather than `assigns(:user)`?

Comment: I've tried with both. Using :user sends me to an id, but this redirect uses the objects url instead of the id.

Comment: Can you post your controller method?

Comment: I just got it. Thanks for putting me on the right path with assigns.

Comment: I know you solved this and of course that's great. But I'm thinking here why that route is working with a string as a parameter instead of an ActiveRecord object or a hash...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
it 'redirects to users#show' do
  post :create, user: attributes_for(:guest)
  expect(response).to redirect_to guest_path(assigns(:guest))
end
```

In this case, `assigns(:guest)` will be equal to the instance variable with the same name as the arguments (`:guest`) that was returned by the request you're testing for.

Comment: I initially used something similar form the rspec book. I get an error     
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"guest", :url=>nil} But thanks.

Comment: Hey, don't be so quick to assume the test must be wrong. You may have some routing problem in there.

Comment: The test output is exactly what I want. (http://test.host/guest/zaOVsiPBwQ4yNnC0mJNoNA) But the way I've written the test, it thinks I want something else back.

Comment: Please note it's `assigns(:guest)`, not `assigns(:user)`.